# How to Rig in easy and simple way

Tags: rigging

I have finish my new character with material. Time to rig and pose the character.

[image]

I want to know is there any addon or tutorial which can help me to rig my character or pose. I want my character to hold a stick in hand. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use the Rigify add-on.
Check the tutorial « [Quick Rigging With Rigify in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYiAd_08-0k) » from CG Cookie.

Comment: Thanks for replying and the link. I want my character to be pose. I tried with the riggify addon. But i want to my character to have a punch or holding stick in hand style. I have to rotate all the 5 finger to make the shape as if its holding and not looking natural. Is there any way that all the finger can be control to make a punch shape or a holding shape.

Comment: Yes there is a way, but it's not something easy and quick to make. You need a few seconds to move a bunch of fingers. You need a few minutes (if you know how to do) to create an automated fist pose system.

Answer (score 0):

Put the stick in the characters hand.
then pose the fingers to grip it.
Go to your rigs object data tab and create a new pose library. it is closer to the bottom of the tab.
[image: pose library location]

when you click new you will get a new window that pops up right under it.
select the finger and wrist bones then press the plus button on the right and call it closed fist or something.
Note that if you want to re apply this pose just select the bones again and click the orange magnifying glass thing at the bottom right
[image]

then select your stick and go to the object constraints tab
and give it a child of constraint

[image]

Select the target as your character's rig and the bone as it's wrist
[image: child of constraint]

then make sure to click the set inverse button or you will get some weird effects. And if you want the guy to drop the stick just slide the influence slide down to zero.